# How to make the wordpress back end editor theme to main theme?

Tags: css, wordpress

Wordpress' back end editor is absolutely beautiful, which CSS can I edit to make the backend theme into my main theme (Super Minimal Theme: https://wordpress.org/themes/super-minimal/)?

Here's what the back end looks like:
[image: https://wordpress.org/themes/super-minimal/]

My current front end (font doesn't look nearly as nice):
[image]

Here's my site: http://socialarts.com

Comment: It's because your theme CSS does not reflect your backend editor. Gutenberg editor structure the content but how it looks like front-end it depends on your theme CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gutenburg editor uses the Noto Serif font.
To add that style to your H2 headings of the theme use this CSS:

```
article h2, article h2 a {
    font-family: "Noto Serif",serif;
    font-size: 42px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 1.4;
    color: black;
}
body p {
    font-family: "Noto Serif", serif;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #191e23;
}
```

And if you want to remove that border at the bottom add this:

```
article h2, article h2 a {
border-bottom: none;
}
```